# emulator location service not working on android studio giraffe

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

It's been two days since I can't see the map as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

I tried them all, deleted and recreated emulators and even uninstalled android studio and reinstalled. None of these things fixed the problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not only mine but it was a known issue some time ago. However, apparently there was a breaking change to the Google Maps javascript API now and this caused the problem again.
I leave below the issue that was opened and closed when the problem was solved in the past, it has now been reopened.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228201899